# Cron running "docker exec" make my server freeze

Tags: php, docker, cron

I need help to solve a problem with a cron running a `docker exec` command.

After setting up this cron, my server sometimes gets not responding anymore. No web requests handled, no SSH connection possible. I must restart the server to get it back. It usually happens 3 or 4 times per day.

My cron is setup in my host's crontab :

```
* * * * * docker exec -w /home/current myphpapp-container bash -c "php artisan schedule:run >> storage/logs/schedule.log"
```

I'm pretty sure the cron is faulty here because I never had this problem before the cron installation and I don't get it when I disable the cron script.

Docker version is "18.06.3-ce".
The container is a "php:8.0-fpm".
OS is "Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)".

I searched into syslog and others but did not find anything interesting. My cron is minute but I don't even see any progressive load increasing along time. I'm a bit stuck...

Do you have any ideas ? Where should I look to find relevant logs ?

Comment: Could you `docker run` a new container instead?  This would produce logs normally that you could review with `docker logs` or other normal techniques.

Comment: I have 4 scheduled commands run by the parent command `php artisan schedule:run` launched by the cron. I can see they are working as expected. I can event see the new processes appear inside my `myphpapp-container` at the moment of the run and then disappear when finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally, it looks like a "Docker engine 18.06" related problem. I created a new fresh server with OS and Docker engine up to date. Problem is gone.